# Every point in open set belongs to component interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm currently self studying analysis, and I'm reading Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, which proves the following statement about component intervals.

**Definition of component interval:** *Let $S$ be an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^1$, An open interval $I \subseteq S$ is a component interval if there does not exist an open interval $J\ne I$ such that $I \subseteq J \subseteq S$.*

> **Statement**. Prove that every point of a nonempty open set S belongs to one and only one component interval of $S$.

**Proof.** Assume $x \in S$. then $x$ is contained in some open interval $I$ with $I \subseteq S$. There are many such intervals but the "largest" of these will be the desired component interval. We leave it to the reader to verify that the largest interval is $(a(x), b(x))$, where $a(x) =$ inf $\{ a: (a,x) \subseteq S\}$ and $b(x) =$ sup $\{ b: (x,b) \subseteq S\}$. (The proof continues...)

This is intuitively true, since any interval greater than this obviously contains points that are not in $S$. I've tried defining such a point but am unable to show that it doesn't lie in $S$. Can someone prove this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, neither $I_{\epsilon}:=(a(x)-\epsilon,b(x))$ nor $J_{\epsilon}:=(a(x),b(x)+\epsilon)$ are contained in $S$.

Since $\epsilon>0$, there is a point $y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a(x)-\epsilon<y<a(x)$. Since $y<a(x)$, it follows by the definition of the infimum that $(y,x)$ is not a subset of $S$. Since $a(x)-\epsilon<y$, $(y,x)\subset I_{\epsilon}$.  Therefore, $I_{\epsilon}$ cannot be a subset of $S$.

Similarly, one can show that $J_{\epsilon}$ is not a subset of $S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly which part of the definition of infimum shows that $(y,x)$ is not a subset?

Comment: Well, let's suppose that $(y,x)\subset S$. Then, $y\in\{a:(a,x)\subset S\}$. But then $a(x)\leq y$, by the fact that $a(x)$ is the infimum of the set $\{a:(a,x)\subset S\}$. Thus, we have a contradiction since we also have that $y<a(x)$.

Comment: (+1) Of course this reasoning implicitly assumed that $S$ is bounded so are the intervals $(a(x),b(x))$.